Meaning of getting bad dreams in islam
I got bad dreams continously in one night. After I had 1st bad dream I recited the dua and slept. But still I got another one.after I woke up for subah. Even after praying subah i still got nightmare.  What is the reason for that?

People on the site are not clairvoyant. There is no way for us to know the reason that you experienced bad dreams, It could be that you were stressed or it could be mere coincidence or it could be that satan is messing with you, or it could be something else.

Ohh jazakallahu hairen
